# Segmented Control exe_bad_instruction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I created a segmented control and the code compiles, but when I click on a new index I get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. It says that it is a exe_bad_instruction and highlights the switch line.
What am I missing or did I set up wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl?) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
       case 0:
           textLabel.text = "First Segment Selected";
       case 1:
           textLabel.text = "Second Segment Selected";
       default:
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: segmentedControl or selectedSegmentIndex are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `switch` line to this (I added the question mark):

```
switch segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex
```

You'll need to read up on [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) and [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) in Swift to understand why this helps.

Now your app won't crash, but you'll have to figure out why your `segmentedControl` is `nil` at that point. I cannot help with that as you have not posted enough code to diagnose. However I would start by determining if you really want your `segmentedControl` held by a `weak` property.